# Is it possible to override the echo function for website header in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I currently have a [website](https://barkingmouse.com.au/blog/) set up on Wordpress that is displaying the most recent posts in a grid. Currently the website is referencing the title of the most recent post and using that as the page title. (eg. Blog post is called the Unlikeables, the page title reads "The Unlikeables" when it should read "The Scratch", when I change the post name, the page title changes).

It appears that wordpress is using the index.php file to build this particular page. I know this as when I went into the index.php and added `<h2> test </h2>` it was reflected on the page.

Currently the start of the code reads

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">

            <div class="row text-center box-blog-row">

                <?php 
                $counter = 1;
                while (have_posts()): ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                    <?php the_post(); ?>
```

Which code do I have to update if I want the page title to remain a fixed title "The Scratch"?

Comment: A few questions, are you using a custom built theme? or is it one you bought(if so are you using a child theme?) The code for the page title is most likely in the header.php file so if you could shaw a sample code snippet of that I could help.

Comment: Yes, custom built. You were right, I didn't believe it would be in the header due to the homepage layout being stored in the header.php but realised that obviously the get_header was getting more than just the nav bar and company logo. Posted the answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging in the header.php and found what I was looking for in:

```
<div class="header black"><h2><span>THE SCRATCH</span></h2></div>
    <?php } else { ?>
<div class="header black"><h2><span><?php echo get_post_field('post_title', intval(get_the_ID()));?></span></span></h2></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The 'else' statement applied to the blog page so I changed the content in the header tag and fixed the issue.